# Where is the $-2$ coming from?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

If $y=x +\frac 1x$, how is $x^2 + \frac1{x^2} = y^2 - 2$. 
Shouldn't the answer be just $y^2$, where is the $-2$ coming from.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Square both sides and use the binomial expansion.

Comment: $(a+b)^2$ isn't $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Well, it is if we're working in a field of characteristic $2$. =P

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, i get it now.

Comment: @shark I beg your pardon, $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$.  That would be in nimbers, of course.

Comment: @OscarLanzi ???

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber

Comment: @OscarLanzi Heh. I'd never seen the word "nimber" - looked like "number"...

Answer (score 6):

Because $$y^2=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2.$$
We used $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab.$

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 = x^2+2\frac{x}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2} =x^2+2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Comment: I fixed your post. +1.

Comment: Thank you and already +1ed : )

Answer (score 1):

It is $$y^2=x^2+2\times x\times\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$$

With the above formula in mind try to expand $$y^2=(x+\frac {1}{x})^2 =x^2+2+\frac {1}{x^2}$$ and you find your $-2$